# Card Positioning in IE 11 is different then Firefox

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I'am trying to build responsive website using Materialized framework. I am having issue where my card positioning is not correct in IE. However, It is working fine in Firefox. I am not sure where the problem is occuring. My assumption is something related to the margin I've set to Auto.

I've tried to correct it in Style.CSS and Materialized.CSS in main {} and body {}. But still having issue.

Container:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Structure:

```
<main>

  <div class="container main-content">

    <!-- Test Automation Cards -->


    <div class="col s12" style="padding-top: 40px;padding-bottom: 50px;text-align: center">
      <p class="flow-text center">Design Tools</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center;">


      <div class="col s12 m6 l4" style="flex: 20%; max-width: 30%;box-sizing: border-box;padding: 15px;">
        <a href="http://agilehq/" target="_blank">
          <div class="card waves-effect">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="img/agile.png">
              <span class="card-title"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" style="text-align: center">
              <p>Search Design Documents</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m6 l4" style="flex: 20%; max-width: 30%;box-sizing: border-box;padding: 15px;">
        <a href="http://sharepoint/sites/wip/WorkInProgress/Forms/Project.aspx" target="_blank">
          <div class="card waves-effect">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="img/folder.png">
              <span class="card-title"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" style="text-align: center">
              <p>WIP ShareDrive</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m6 l4" style="flex: 20%; max-width: 30%;box-sizing: border-box;padding: 15px;">
        <a href="http://crdr/" target="_blank">
          <div class="card waves-effect">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="img/tfs.jpg">
              <span class="card-title"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" style="text-align: center">
              <p>CRDR</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


</main>
```

Main:

```
main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Output is different in Firefox then IE.

Check Both Screenshot [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8VII.jpg).

Comment: You're using https://materializecss.com ?

Comment: yes I am using Materialize CSS

Comment: Looks like IE11 has a bug with the third value of flex: 
["IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property"](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex). More info in the Known Issues section of that link. Not sure if that is what is causing your issue though.